# Pandas Styling - Coloring cells of specific columns instead of entire DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, styling

I wrote the following block of code to colour some cells in my dataframe.

```
def applycolor(dtf):

        return ['background-color: lightgreen' if x >= 1500  else 
        ('background-color: lightskyblue' if 1000 <= x < 1500  else 
        'background-color: pink' if 750 <= x < 1000 else
        'background-color: wheat' if  550 <= x < 750 else 
        'background-color: paleturquoise' if 330 <= x < 550  else 
        'background-color: darkseagreen' if 150 <= x < 330 else 'background-color: default') for x in dtf]    


cs1 = cs.style.apply(applycolor, axis=0)
```

This gave me a result as shown in the image.

[image]
However, I only want the colors to be rendered for the figures specified in `df['$-Score']`. But this styling appended colours to all the relevant numerics of the dataframe as seen.

I tried to change last line of the list comprehension to include only the particular column of the dataframe like so: `.....if 150 <= x < 330 else 'background-color: default') for x in dtf['$-Score']`- but it returned an error.

Have tried looking for the specific answer, but haven't been able to find it. Any ideas?

Alternatively, a SAMPLE DATAFRAME:

```
    A    B   C
0   83  76  30
1   34  17  44
2   72  16  94
3   24  94  27
4   98  36  35
5   41  77  39
6   65  54  18
7   85  1   59
8   12  79  2
9   33  57  76
10  66  69  100
11  99  51  89
12  24  74  32
13  51  98  63
14  63  36  82
15  53  52  65
```

I only want numbers between 55 and 58 to be coloured red in column B and Blue between 84 and 87 in column C only.

How can I go about it?

Comment: please provide a sample dataframe too?

Comment: Won't be possible to provide the same dataframe honestly. But you can make a random one with 3 columns A B C with numerical data ( random numbers in range 0 to 100) in each and highlight all numbers between 50 and 55 in column B only and between 84 and 87 in column C only. You'll get a better idea that way.

Comment: exactly what you said, can you add that in the question as a sample? on which your function would work

Comment: @anky_91 I've put in a sample dataframe. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Style.apply` works just like `DataFrame.apply` in that the dataframe is broken into series, and in your case you want to do something different based on each series's name (i.e., column name). So the below example can be extended for your purposes:

```
def apply_formatting(col):
    if col.name == 'a':
        return ['background-color: red' if c > 50 else '' for c in col.values]
    if col.name == 'b':
        return ['background-color: green' if c > 10 else '' for c in col.values]
    if col.name == 'c':
        return ['background-color: blue' if c > 30 else '' for c in col.values]

data = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0, 100, 30).reshape(10, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

data.style.apply(apply_formatting)  # axis=0 by default
```

Here is the result on the random data:

[image]

Comment: This works for the sample. But when I add .name == 'xyz' I get a reshape error. Why is that happening?

Comment: I found the solution. The real solution was using 'subset' = {column name} in the df.style syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `subset` property

```py
df.style.apply(your_func, subset=['column_name'])
```